# Class, interface or enum expected

Tags: java, inheritance, enums

I have to name all the errors in this code, but I don't know is wrong in class B i got the error class, interface or enum expected. What does that mean?

```
public abstract class A {
    private double a;
    public A(A r){
        a = r.a;
    }

    public A(double a){
        this.a = a;
    }

    public double ma(){
        return a;
    }

    public abstract int mv();
    }

    public class B extends A {
        private int b;
        public B() {
            super(); //ne postoji konstruktor
        }

        public B(B o) {
            b=o.b; 
        } //nije pozvan odgovarajuci konstruktor
    }

    public B(int r) { 
        super(b); b=r; 
    } //HERE
}
```

Comment: public class inside a public class? please paste the exception too

Comment: Brace missing:     public abstract int mv();  }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with errors-

i) `public B() {
            super(); //ne postoji konstruktor
        }`

super() will call constructor `public A(){}` in class A but it is not defined. Since, you have defined other constructors in class A() , you need to explicitly define default no-arg constructor (minimum visibility should be protected).

ii) `public B(int r) { 
        super(b); b=r; 
    } //HERE`
    super(b);b =r . You should define a variable before you can use. What is b here? Where is it declared. This should be

`public B(double r) { 
        super(r);
    } //HERE` 
I changed the type of r as double because if it was integer than super(r) expects a constructor in class A with type as integer.

iii) You are closing class B before `public B(double r) { super(r);} //HERE`
Remove the } brace above this code.

iv) Last one - `mv` is an unimplemented method in class A and B extends A (B is not abstract). So, B should implement this method. `public int mv() {//Body }`

Answer (score 0):

you have too many errors here...

```
public B(int r) { //BODY }
```

It should be

`public void B(int r) { //BODY }`